# cannot move the position of href with by modifying margin

Tags: html, css

```css
.butn{
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background:black;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <a href="#" class="butn">Clear</a>
</body>
```

What I am working on is `href` that works like a `button` function. However, when I try to position this so called "button" with anything margin related like `margin-top` and `margin-right`, it does not change the position of this href. So my question is how do I move the position of this (href with padding)

Comment: display:inline-block to the link

Answer (score 0):

Put the margins in style attribute.

```
 <a href="#" style="margin-top:15px; margin-right:5px" class="butn">Clear</a>
```

It seems margins of html `<a></a>` tag in a style like buttons doesn’t work. I faced the same problem and handled it like this.
I am not clear why this works(!?!). But I shared my experience.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This isn't a good answer. The reason the OP's code doesn't work is that margins and related positional attributes don't work on inline elements.

Comment: So, answer how can you handle this?

Comment: It Doesn't Work!

Comment: the answer is add a "display:inline-block" to it

Comment: It Doesn't work after adding 'inline-block'